# Passing props to Layout for dynamic routes (App Router) in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I want to pass props to Layout for some dynamic routes.
This is the project structure:

```
/app
-/(site)
--/layout.tsx
--/page.tsx
--/[slug]/page.tsx
--/[slug]/layout.tsx
```

in the site layout:

```
export default async function IndexRoute({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const settings = await getSettings()

  const layout = (
    <html  lang='en'>
      <body>
        <div className='flex min-h-screen flex-col'>
          <a className='sr-only' href='#mainContent'>
            Skip to content
          </a>
          <Suspense>
            <Masthead />
          </Suspense>
          <main className='flex flex-1 flex-col ' id='mainContent'>
            <Suspense>{children}</Suspense>
          </main>
          <Suspense>
            <Foundation menus={settings.menus.footer} />
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
  return layout
}
```

Apparently this layout will consider the [slug] layout as a nested layout. My goal here is to create a layout for the [slug] routes so I can pass props to that layout.
How can I solve this?

Comment: @LandonSchropp Can you please explain what your goal is? Why do you want to pass props to layout? The answer below is true, but it doesn't help you achieve your goal. Please tag me so that I can see your comment.

Comment: @RokBenko If you go to my website (https://www.landonschropp.com/notes) and click around on different items, you'll see different pages have different themes based on the category. Since these include the main navigation for the site, I wanted to set a theme data attribute on the `body` element that'd be accessed by child components for styling.

I did this at runtime, but ideally I'd be able to do it at build time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no communication between a page and a layout.

`page.tsx` is rendered as the `children` component of the layout. [From here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout)

> Unlike Pages, Layout components do not receive the searchParams prop.
> This is because a shared layout is not re-rendered during navigation
> which could lead to stale searchParams between navigations.

That is because a layout file serves as a template or structural framework that defines the overall structure, design, and arrangement of elements for multiple pages within a website or web application. It does not rerender so user always see the layout components on the browser even when they navigate to another page.